# Android Error: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently, I create an apps with a login function. To connect from android to MySQL database, I use PHP. When I use MySQLi, everything is okay. But when I convert to PDO, The error will appear the same as my question's title. Can anyone knows what is the problem? Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

    require_once 'configPDO.php';

    $response = array();

        if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('badgeid', 'pwd'))){

            $badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];
            $pwd = $_POST['pwd']; 

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT badgeid, email, fullname, roles_id, team_id FROM users WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND pwd = :pwd AND roles_id = 3");
            // $stmt->bind_param("ss",$badgeid, $pwd);

            $stmt->bindParam(':badgeid',$badgeid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pwd',$pwd,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            //$stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

                $stmt->bindParam($badgeid, $email, $fullname, $roles_id, $team_id);
                $stmt->fetch();

                $user = array(
                    'badgeid'=>$badgeid, 
                    'email'=>$email,
                    'fullname'=>$fullname,
                    'roles_id'=>$roles_id,
                    'team_id'=>$team_id
                );

                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
                $response['user'] = $user; 
            }else{
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';
            }
        }
    echo json_encode($response);

    function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

        foreach($params as $param){
            if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: Seems that you encounter here an server error. Take a look into the raw response (before converting to JSON) you get back from the server.

Comment: what is mean by raw response?

Comment: The original response you get from the server, before you convert it into JSON.

How does your client side (android) code looks?

Comment: @CodyKL you want to help me on this? I can give the android code

Comment: @Dharman can you highlight where are the mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

Your second `bindParam()` (You should read and understand what exactly this method do!) inside the `if` condition is nonsense!

Change this:

```php
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

    $stmt->bindParam($badgeid, $email, $fullname, $roles_id, $team_id);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $user = array(
        'badgeid'=>$badgeid, 
        'email'=>$email,
        'fullname'=>$fullname,
        'roles_id'=>$roles_id,
        'team_id'=>$team_id
    );
```

to this:

```php
$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Get results as array
if ($result) {
    // Since we only get the fields we want to send back, you can assign `$result` directly to `$response['user']`
     $response['user'] = $result;
```

PHP had thrown an related error, which you would have seen in the raw response of you request!

Comment: fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)?

Comment: what inside the fetch?

Comment: `fetch()` use `\PDO::FETCH_BOTH` as default, since we want to access the result directly by the field names, we set `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as fetch style, this reduces the array, otherwise you have for each column value 2 entries, 1 with numbered key, one with field name as key.

For more information refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I've updated the code above, `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` is not needed here, you can just check `$result` directly.

Comment: Still got error. I Have updated my question here, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259039/json-error-cannot-login-the-android-apps